# Json response returns nested object

Tags: laravel, vue.js, response

I am new in vue laravel and trying to get data from API controller with json response. I feel its not in best practices that I get data in nested object. Whats the best way to implement this so that I can get `this.user_data.designations = All_Designation(with res.data)` and some other like   `this.user_data.employment = All_Employments`, etc.

Also when I try to send data via props I can access it as

```
designations:  this.data.map(d => ({label: d.designation_name, value: d.designation_name, id:d.id}))
```

I want other data also so I guess it should be like `this.data.designations`, `this.data.employment`. This made me confused. **how can I manage everything** without changing things in trait?

This is my controller method:

```
public function index()
{
    $designations = Designation::all();
    if (!$designations->isEmpty()) {
        $this->responseData['response'] = 1;
        $this->responseData['message'] = "Designations has been Recieved.";
        $this->responseData['data'] = $designations;
        $this->status = 200;
    }
    return $this->apiResponse();
}
```

Api trait:

```
protected $responseData = [
    'response' => 0,
    'message' => "Not Found",
    'data' => null
];
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $status = 404;
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function apiResponse()
{
    return response()->json($this->responseData, $this->status);
}
```

Axios Call:

```
this.$store.dispatch('employee/getDesignations' )
    .then(res => { this.user_data.designations = res.data.data })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err) 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return response like this

```
return response()->json(['response' => ['status' => true, 'data' => $apiResponse]], JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
```

HTTP_OK =200  and its a enum type of `use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;`
status =true mean you returning the data .

for example if your data is empty then return something like this

```
return response()->json(['response' => ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to find data ']], JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
```

just return this .

```
return response()->json($data, JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
```

hope this will hel you

Comment: i appreciate your effort but it became more nested. Now I am getting data by response.data.data which is not good thing i guess

Comment: return response()->json($data, JsonResponse::HTTP_OK); use this